# How glOrtho2D Works

Tags: opengl

```
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

gluOrtho2D(10, 100, 10, 100);
```

I am not getting any output, can you help me?

If I set it to

```
gluOrtho2D(-50, 50,-50, 50);
```

Then object created at center of window.

Comment: Are you sure that you understand what `ortho` does and means?

Answer (score 10):

`gluOrtho2D(left, right, top, bottom)` defines a view box. That means that there is no perspective.

With

```
gluOrtho2D(-50,50,-50,50);
```

you say (assuming you have no additional model view matrix):

- The viewport's left edge is located at world position x = -50
- The viewport's rightedge is located at world position x = +50
- The viewport's top edge is located at world position y = -50
- The viewport's bottomedge is located at world position y = +50

If then your object appears at the screen's center, it is probably located at the world's origin.

If you specify

```
gluOrtho2D(10,100,10,100);
```

then you can see an x-range of 10 to 100. The origin is not within this range and therefore not visible (it is beyond the left edge of the viewport).

Note that there are apparently two different signatures of this function based on the API:
[`gluOrtho2D(left, right, bottom, top)`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluOrtho2D.xml) and [`gluOrtho2D(left, right, top, bottom)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368673(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Can you without any doubt say that the OP did not research? Maybe he did some research but did not understand most of the stuff. After all there is plenty of terminology and maths that needs to be known.

Comment: you got the definition wrong.  it's left, right, bottom, top (bottom and top are reversed).

Comment: @thang As mentioned in the last paragraph, this depends on the API.

Comment: oh sorry.  i totally missed that.  did you try the microsoft version?  i wonder if it's a mistake in the documentation.

Comment: @thang Good question. I just checked my Windows SDK and there it is `bottom, top`.

Comment: so microsoft's online doc is wrong.  i've never seen it as top, bottom other than  on that one page.